# Convert DataFrame Column with Month names to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```html
  Months      Employed Canadians
1   January   204,571
2   February    204,634
3   March       195,656
4   April       173,783
5   May       179,142
6   June        197,385
7   July        204,248
```

I have a dataframe with month names as strings. I want to convert to dateTime.
[image: the month table is an object]

The month column is an object and I want to convert it to Datetime.

Comment: note that datetime dtype won't allow you to have *only* the month. default year/day/time will be added if you don't specify it.

Comment: if you just want to convert the month name to a number to work with, you could use `pd.to_datetime(df['Months'], format='%B').dt.month`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the year at least in order to convert to `datetime`

```
df['Months'] = pd.to_datetime('2020' + df.Months, format='%Y%B')
Out[26]: 
1   2020-01-01
2   2020-02-01
3   2020-03-01
4   2020-04-01
5   2020-05-01
6   2020-06-01
7   2020-07-01
Name: Months, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: technically, you don't *have* to explicitly specify a year (see my comment on the question); it's just that the default year 1900 seems kind of ...old ;-)